# How to get type of a column from a cursor ?- Android

Tags: android, android-cursor

anyone know how to get the type of a column from a cursor in Android (SQLite), my API target is 17 and I read about the cursor.getType() method only work before the API 11.

I need it to use a function that create a xml to send to a WebService in .Net to persist the data in SQL DB.

Solution:

```
   _db.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info(tableName)", null);
```

And this return a cursor with the data (name, type, is nullable..) of the table.

Comment: getType works starting from API 11 so you should be ok

Comment: Thanks Alex for the answer,but I have this problem when I use cursor.getType(int) " Method "getType" with signature "(I)I" is not applicable on this object "